# Error when entering array from keyboard

Tags: java, arrays

```
package array;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = input.nextInt();
        int[] a = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println(a);

    }

}
```

Comment: and what error is it..?

Comment: n= 5 a = {3 4 6 7 9} on screen: [I@647e05

Comment: @IQ246 that is not an Error it prints the array `Object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot print an array directly, you have to iterate through it's values.

```
for (int j=0;j<a.length;j++){
  System.out.println(a[j]); 
}
```